# Display variable error pyautogui

Tags: python, jenkins, environment-variables, pytest, pyautogui

I am using pyautogui and pytest to automate the testing of a GUI app (python pyqt, pyside). My tests run without errors when I run from command line but gives me following error while importing pyautogui when I am running through jenkins:

```
tests/test_enlighten.py:1: in <module>
import re, sys, signal, logging, argparse, pyautogui, subprocess
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py:115: in <module>
from . import _pyautogui_x11 as platformModule
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py:160: in 
<module>
_display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py:23: in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key)
E   KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```

I read about setting DISPLAY variable and tried this

```
new_env = dict(os.environ)
new_env['DISPLAY'] = '0.0'
```

I tried 'localhost:0' value instead but it still failed.

```
E   DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display "localhost:0": [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Any direct help or recommended reading would be appreciated.

Comment: That's because when you run the tests locally, you have a display available where the SuT is drawn. Jenkins runs in a headless mode, not having a display to draw. Install `xvfb` on the Linux machine running Jenkins and run the tests via `xvfb-run pytest` instead of `pytest`. This will run the tests with a virtual display where the UI will be rendered.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xvfb/

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution for this particular problem which worked perfectly for me. [This is only for linux users]

Open terminal and execute the following command:

xhost +SI:localuser:root

That's all.

Thanks to mooze@github.com. I got this solution from there.

Link: https://github.com/mooz/xkeysnail/commit/9f3a79ab77eea6c581414bbbcc3b90db5eff5c26

Answer (score -1):

I have also got the same problem. But the problem only occurs when I use sudo. Which means the problem only exist if I run the python script as a superuser and thus I tried to avoid being superuser while using pyautogui and the problem disappeared.

Hope it helps.